# VueJS and dynamic reload ChartJS when screen resize

Tags: chart.js, vue.js

I'm trying to figure out, how I can reload my ChartJS components whenever the screensize is changed as it's messing up the responsiveness at the moment. My goal is to either reload them after resize, or remove them while resizing and loading again after resize.

This is my code so far for the graph component, for some reason it's ignoring the timer, but maybe the `ready()` isn't just called when the component is loaded?

```
export default {
    props: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            data: {
                labels: ['2014', '2015', '2016', '2016'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Administration",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 219, 77, 0.5)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(255, 219, 77, 1)",
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 219, 77, 0.8)",
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 219, 77, 1)",
                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81],
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Teaching",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 166, 77, 0.5)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(255, 166, 77, 1)",
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 166, 77, 0.8)",
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 166, 77, 1)",
                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81],
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Exam & Supervision",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 153, 204, 0.5)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(102, 153, 204, 1)",
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(102, 153, 204, 0.8)",
                        hoverBorderColor: "rgba(102, 153, 204, 1)",
                        data: [65, 59, 80, 81],
                    }
                ]
            },

            timoutHandle: null
        }
    },

    ready() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.reload);
        this.loadChart();
    },

    methods: {
        loadChart() {
            console.log('loading..');

            new Chart(
                this.$el.getContext('2d'),
                {
                    type: this.type,
                    data: this.data,
                    options: {
                        legend: {
                            position: 'bottom'
                        }
                    }
                }
            ); 
        },

        reload() {
            window.clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);

            this.timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(
                this.loadChart(),
            3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using vue-charts? It's google-chart wrapper for vue and it exports draw method and resizing on window size change is quite easy:

```
<template>
  <vue-chart
  :chart-type="chartType"
  :columns="columns"
  :chart-events="chartEvents"
  :rows="rowData"
  :options="options"
  v-ref:thisherechart
  ></vue-chart>
</template>

ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    jQuery(window).resize(function () {
      self.$refs.thisherechart.drawChart();
    })
  },
```

Same jQuery may help You with your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that's something to consider. Does Google charts require jQuery? I don't use it so I prefer not to need it.

Comment: Nope - i just used jQuerry for window resize hook :)

Comment: Maybe a general rule for redoing canvases is what I'm needing.. hmm.. just thinking, have been struggling with this for some days now. I really want to keep ChartJS for now.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this part of the problem, look here for reference: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2777#issuecomment-226219784